# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un archivo sin que el usuario tenga que seleccionarlo manualmente?

Tags: java, android, archivo, android-intent, fileupload

Tengo un botón que al presionarlo lanza una activity para seleccionar un documento PDF

```
btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.setType("application/pdf");
        chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult(chooseFile, REQ_PDF);
    }
});
```

Al documento seleccionado lo codifico en base64 y lo almaceno en mi variable `encodedPDF`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQ_PDF && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri path = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);
            byte[] pdfInBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(pdfInBytes);
            encodedPDF = Base64.encodeToString(pdfInBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            textView.setText("Document Selected");
            btnSelect.setText("Change Document");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Document Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Luego tengo otro botón que lee la variable y la envía a un servidor

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        uploadDocument();
    }
});
```

```
private void uploadDocument() {
    Call<ResponsePOJO> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getAPI().uploadDocument(encodedPDF);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePOJO>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponsePOJO> call, Response<ResponsePOJO> response) {           
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getRemarks(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponsePOJO> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Todo esto lo copié de un tutorial y funciona perfecto. Sin embargo el primer botón no tiene sentido en mi app porque el pdf que quiero subir está siempre en la misma ruta que conozco de antemano

```
File path = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + Login.gIdPedido + " Examen.pdf")));
```

Lo que quiero es deshacerme de esa primera parte de seleccionar el documento pero no sé cómo implementarlo.

¿Cómo puedo omitir la selección manual del PDF y obtenerlo directamente del almacenamiento al momento de darle al botón de enviar?

Comment: Android tiene una serie de herramientas modernas para realizar tareas en 2º plano. La clave es que elijas la herramienta adecuada para lo que quieres hacer, te recomiendo que leas la [*Guía para el procesamiento en segundo plano*](https://developer.android.com/guide/background), y cuando tengas claro el tipo de proceso que realmente necesitas para este caso, entonces uses la herramienta que Android recomienda. Por ejemplo, ¿necesitas que ese archivo se suba al servidor cada X tiempo? ¿qué debe ocurrir si no hay conexión, debe diferirse la subida, debe anularse, debe reintentarse más tarde etc?

Comment: La pregunta es innecesariamente larga pero aún así no es clara. Cuál es el problema exactamente? Parece que quieres obtener un PDF sin usar un intent pero también dices "*he implementado mi propia lógica para obtener el PDF generado*" ¿Cuál es esa lógica y cómo es que eso no resuelve tu problema? Lo que entiendo es que no tienes inconvenientes para enviar el PDF sino para leerlo del dispositivo. Es decir que **tu pregunta no está relacionada con retrofit, php ni mysql**. Por favor, coloca sólo el código que sea relevante para la pregunta.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que no comprendiste lo que trato de hacer @SinneroftheSystem el código es necesario porque partiendo de ese código se resuelve mi pregunta por ejemplo la opción que me da Cedano probablemente sea una posible solución pero no logro implementarla de la forma me que lo ha dicho! pddddd: el voto negativo no era necesario

Comment: Ok pero podrías explicarlo un poco mejor? Tal vez pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Tratare de hacerlo @SinneroftheSystem La pregunta es clara al menos para mi, he seguido un tutorial para insertar un PDF en la base de datos y para esto debo subirlo al servidor entonces esto ya esta hecho pero el problema es que según el tutorial que he seguido el PDF debo buscarlo manualmente en el almacenamiento y es eso lo que quiero omitir y enviar el PDF de forma directa sin buscar en el almacenamiento claramente tengo que agregar la ruta del PDF que necesito enviar cuando presione el botón de enviar y para ello tengo que cambiar la lógica que he implementado siguiendo el tutorial.

Comment: Acabo de entender tu pregunta. Sobra mucho texto y mucho código. La pregunta es la siguiente: **¿Cómo puedo pasarle una ruta a `setOnClickListener()` y que se auto adjunte el fichero para ser subido?** Cierto?

Comment: Si quieres que no sea manual, sin botones, ¿En qué momento se va a subir el pdf? ¿Sería al momento de crearlo?; en tal caso suena a que todo el código relacionado con lo botones lo vas borrar, y que todo el `try - catch` del resultado de la actividad lo tienes que mover -no sabemos a dónde- justo después de la creación del pdf junto con tu código -que desconocemos- para obtener el pdf generado, que parece innecesario, ya que al momento de crearlo haz de conocer la ruta de creación.

Comment: Asi es @ICIM eso seria lo que necesito.

Comment: Si @Sal pero lo de la creación ya lo tengo implementado nada mas me faltaría enviarlo a MySQL

Comment: Me refiero a cuando dices *"mi propia lógica para obtener el PDF generado"*, que en este punto ya no sé si quieres decir "para generar los bytes" o "para obtener los bytes del almacenamiento". La respuesta está prácticamente a la vista, pero no tenemos un contexto para indicarte, un lugar exacto en el flujo del código donde existan las variables requeridas. Tu tienes todo el código, pero tampoco queremos verlo todo, y te hemos señalado en mas de una ocasión que nos has proporcionado el código que no quieres utilizar, que nos sirve para entender, mas no para concretar una respuesta.

Comment: Nos ayudaría saber si con el pdf partimos de una ruta, un stream o un arreglo de bytes, o ... ¿?

Comment: Coincido totalmente con Sal. La pregunta se entiende pero siguen faltando detalles para poder responderla apropiadamente. Aunque prácticamente ya lo tienes resuelto. Me parece que copiaste el código de un tutorial sin entender lo que hacía y por ello no sabes como implementar algo que en realidad es más simple que lo que tienes actualmente.

Comment: Vaya es que parece que la pregunta no fue muy bien comprendida desde el inicio mira en primer lugar empezare explicando como funciona la aplicación, la aplicación es una toma de pedidos cuando el usuario termina de hacer el pedido se genera un PDF que se guarda en el almacenamiento del usuario y pues obviamente utilizo itext 7 para crear el PDF y guardarlo cuando el usuario finaliza el pedido, posteriormente a eso necesito que además de guardarse en el almacenamiento también se inserte en la base de datos.

Comment: Cuando yo mencione esto "mi propia lógica para obtener el PDF generado" es porque el usuario tiene una opcion para ver sus pedidos entonces hago lo siguiente para que el usuario pueda ver su pedido : `File path = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + Login.gIdPedido + " Examen.pdf")));` esto con la ayuda de PDFviewer el usuario puede visualizar el PDF en la pantalla, entonces a eso me referia con mi propia logica para obtenerlo ahora ya que tengo mi propia logica para obtenerlo me faltaria enviarlo a MySQL

Comment: Espero que ahora si se haya comprendido si no me puedes decir cual código quitar y cual poner para que la pregunta sea mejor @Sal

Comment: Esos últimos comentarios deberías ponerlos en la pregunta, explicando también en que parte tienes ese código. Lo que sobra es la parte de retrofit, php y mysql. Una vez que el PDF entra en `uploadDocument`, ya no importa lo que siga porque entendí que esa parte funciona correctamente. Aunque no fuera así, eso sería una pregunta diferente que debería ir en otro post. También podrías quitar la palabra "adjunte" porque puede hacer pensar que quieres enviar el pdf por mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente debes conectar las piezas:

- Tienes un método `uploadDocument` que envía el PDF que esté en la
  variable `encodedPDF`.
- Luego dentro de `onActivityResult` tienes un código que a paritr una
  `Uri` genera una string base64 y la almecena en esa variable.
- Finalmente dices tener la ruta del arhivo.

Entonces todo lo que tienes que hacer es sacar el código de `onActivityResult` y ponerlo en un método que puedas llamar desde el clickListener, reemplazando la uri resultado del intent por la de tu archivo

```
void encodePDF() {
    File file = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + Login.gIdPedido + " Examen.pdf")));
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        byte[] pdfInBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(pdfInBytes);
        encodedPDF = Base64.encodeToString(pdfInBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Document Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

y simplemente llamalo dentro del clickListener

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        encodePDF();
        uploadDocument();
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfecto, al principio tuve unos problemas pero al final lo logre adaptar a mi código y ya esta funcionando al 100, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Genial! Quieres que mejore la pregunta por tí? Para poder darle un voto positivo

Comment: Si claro estaría genial que la mejores

Comment: Mucho más claro, verdad? Supongo que ahora le ves más sentido a los comentarios que te dejamos. Tómalo como ejemplo para tus próximas preguntas.